# How to turn an overlay into a giant button

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I was wondering how would I turn an overlay into a button? What I don't want is a button that one manually presses to reveal an overlay. What I'd like is automatically when one enters the browser, an overlay is there, and in order to remove it they can click anywhere on the screen and it disappears, letting them interact with the page itself.

Below is the code of the overlay itself, but what would I need to incorporate into it to make it an accessible imaginary button?

...

```
<style>
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

section {
width: 100%;
height: 650px;
background: url("https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/7A715AD8-449D-4B5A-ABA2C5D92D9B5A21_source.png?w=590&h=800&756A88D1-C0EA-4C21-92BE0BB43C14B265");
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgb(105, 105, 105, .9); 
}

#Title {
padding-top: 60px;
font-size: 30px;
color: red;
font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

#sub-text {
font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive;
color: red;
font-size: 25px;
-webkit-text-stroke: .5px black;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
<div class = "overlay">
<div id = "Title">
<h1 align = "center"> Title </h1>
</div>
<div id = "sub-text">
<h2 align = "center">Subtext</h2>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need JS :)

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: 2s;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  visibility: visible;
}
#overlay-handler:checked ~ #overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<input id="overlay-handler" type="radio" hidden>
<label for="overlay-handler" id="overlay">
  <h2>WELCOME.<br>Click anywhere to continue</h2>
</label>
<h1>Hi there...</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked out :) Although, I was wanting to add a subtext underneath heading1 and although the break does help, I'd like 2 seperate texts, maybe a heading 1 and a heading 2, but I'd like them both to have a different text.

Comment: @Ten You can add whatever you want and style however you want as long as they're included inside the label.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the overlay to have `position: fixed` and proper z-index it would cover the page by default.

Then declare a click listener on it to either set its display to none or remove it from the DOM.

Just don't use it as a container for the real content

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('#overlay').addEventListener('click', clickEvent => {
    clickEvent.target.classList.add('invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
  padding: 4em 10%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#overlay.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay">
  Click me to interact
</div>
<div>
  This is the real content <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61034197/how-to-turn-an-overlay-into-a-giant-button">But you can't click me without closing the overlay</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the overlay disappear when the body of the HTML is clicked.

```
<body onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('overlay')[0].style.display = 'none'">
...
</body>
```